# Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. Suppose $g\circ f$ is a bijection. Then $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective onto $C$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I think proving $f$ is injective is fairly simple:

Let $x_1,x_2\in A$ s.t. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then, $g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)$. Thus, as $g\circ f$ is bijective, we have that $x_1=x_2$. Thus, $f$ is injective.

Proving $g$ is onto $C$ is a little more difficult for me. I have the following, but I am unsure of its correctness:

Let $y\in C$. Then, because $g\circ f$ is bijective, there is some $x\in A$ s.t. $g\circ f(x)=y$. Note that $f(x)\in B$. *Thus, $g\circ f(x)\in C$. **Thus, there is some $x\in B$ s.t. $g(x)=y$. Thus, $g$ is onto C.

My uncertainty comes from the leap from * to **. Does this progression follow?

Thanks!

Comment: You have it.  You just need "slick wording".  Instead of stating there is a vague x in B which is different than the x in A, specify *directly* that "for every $y \in C$ the resulting $f(x)$ can satisfy as a $v = f(x) \in B$ such that $g(v) = y$.  Thus g is surjective.  It's exactly what you said... just more confident and clearer.

Comment: The image set $f(A)$ of $f$ is a subset of $B$. Since $g \circ f$ is surjective onto $C$, the function $g:f(A) \to C$ is surjective;  extending the domain of $g$ to $B$ preserves surjectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. As you say there is $x$ in $A$ with $[g \circ f](x)=y.$ Now use that $[g \circ f](x)=g(f(x))$ and give $f(x)$ some name like $f(x)=k.$ This $k$ then lies in $B$ and $g(k)=y$ so that $g$ is onto.

Comment: I'm still pretty new with functions, but your answer is very clear and helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Often a good trick is to give some intermediate thing a temporary name to make a step in an argument clear. You basically had the right idea but the way you explained wasn't absolutely clear, at least to me. Upvoted question especially since you showed a lot of correct steps.

Comment: Another trick is to make it clear that the resulting x is dependent upon y in your naming.  "For every $y \in C$ as $g\circ f$ is bijective, there exists an $x_y \in A$ s.t. $g\circ f(x_y) = y$.  Let $v_y = f(x_y) \in B$.  Thus for every $y \in C$ there exists a $v_y \in B$ s.t. $g(v_y) = y$ so $g$ is surjective."  **Exact** Same thing as the OP did originally, but now it is *crystal* clear and inarguable.

Comment: Yes the subscript gives a good way to notate the dependence of $x$ on $y.$ I typically rely on the verbal part of the argument to convey such dependencies.